# How to Store an Aggregated Value in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and trying to write a stored procedure that will have two components:
 1. Select statement that will return several rows
 2. Another component will have an aggregated value based on some conditions.
 So, for the second component, I am thinking to declare a variable in the stored procedure and store the aggregated data there.
Now, my question is can I populate my output parameter with the data stored in previously declared variable and access the parameter from SSRS 2012?

I would appreciate any suggestion(s) to get me started.

Thank you

Comment: So the stored procedure takes 2 arguments and return a table is that what you need????

Comment: I'm not sure if what you are attempting is possible. I would just add another column and row to your row set. In the report, filter out this extra row on the objects you want to exclude it from: `=isnothing(Fields!YourAggregateColumn.Value)` and use `=max(Fields!YourAggregateColumn.Value,"YourDatasetName")` where you want to display the value.